# How to unset all the mail headers by array key cc and bcc in a loop in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, for-loop, unset

Below is how I tried to unset all the mail header array by cc and bcc.

```
unset(
  $message['cc'], $message['Cc'], $message['CC'],
  $message['headers']['cc'], $message['headers']['Cc'], $message['headers']['CC'],
  $message['params']['headers']['cc'], $message['params']['headers']['Cc'], $message['params']['headers']['CC'],
  $message['bcc'], $message['Bcc'], $message['BCC'],
  $message['headers']['bcc'], $message['headers']['Bcc'], $message['headers']['BCC'],
  $message['params']['headers']['bcc'], $message['params']['headers']['Bcc'], $message['params']['headers']['BCC']
);
```

There are `cc`, `Ccc`, `CCC`, `bcc`, `Bcc` and `BCC`. I know the above solution is not efficient. How can I replace the above code with a shorter code using for-loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array with all the "cc" and "BCC"s and loop it.

```
$items = ["cc","Cc","CC","bcc","Bcc","BCC"];

Foreach($items as $item){
    Unset($message[$item],$message['headers'][$item], $message['params']['headers'][$item]);
}
```

Not sure if I got them all or missed one, but you get the point.